# Trying to run a Python script as sudo with Windows interpreter inside WSL, but got "file not found"

Tags: bash, python, sudo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a python script in my WSL Debian called `pasman`, which is in my home directory `bin` folder, where I keep my custom scripts. I have an `export` statement in `.bashrc` file so that I can run this scripts anywhere on the WSL system. I also has my `bin` folder set in `visudo` file to run scripts as `sudo` when needed.

This python script has a shebang:

```
#!/mnt/c/Users/<MyWindowsUsername>/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe
```

because I want to run it with the Python for Windows interpreter.

The problem is that I want to keep this script owned by `root`, so then I need to run it with `sudo`, but when I do run with `sudo` I got:

```
C:\Users\<MyWindowsUsername>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe: can't open file '/home/<mylinuxusername>/bin/pasman': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

If the script is not owned by `root` and I run it without `sudo`, it runs perfectly.

So, I do not think that the problem is that Windows Python interpreter can't find my script in WSL, but that is it can't find the script only when it's runned with `sudo`, without `sudo` it found the script.

I also do not think that the problem is in the `export` statement in my `.bashrc` file. If it were, then when I tried to run it with `sudo` I will just get something like `sudo: pasman: command not found.`. `sudo` found my `pasman` command even with the `export` in my user `.bashrc`.

Does anyone have any idea  why this is happening?

Comment: What's your Windows release number, whioh is shown by `ver` in a Command Prompt Window? Which version of WSL are you using? Please click [edit] and add this information to your question.

Comment: Try to create a symbolic link of that `python.exe` in WSL and use it in a command.

Comment: @Biswapriyo that's a good idea! Should I create a symbolic link in `/usr/bin` or in my own `bin` directory?

Comment: None worked. Same `[Errno 2] No such file or directory` error. It seems that python.exe interpreter has some problem when trying to run some script with `sudo`.